# html page not full width on google dev tool device toolbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make my website responsive with mobile phones but for some reason when the screen gets small enough there is whitespace on the right side of the phone in which the html page is not the full width, ive tried adding css which include :

```
html
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
}
```

but currently the page looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axz5O.png

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is that white space a scroll bar??

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without knowing all child elements.

You can try adding an outline to all tags like

```
* {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

and check which element is overflowing

Comment: This is really helpful and i appreciate the tip, never thought about doing that, i had elements overflowing i guess, so i got it fixed, thank you!